# How I can create an active client user with custom password for development?

Tags: magento2

For magento development I need to create an active user with custom password via cli. I want this user to be already active and not waiting for password activation.

The user I want to be a client. And I need for local development and quick demonstration.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can use [link] (https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think password activation is default feature of Magento 2.

To allow customer account creation without requiring **Emails Confirmation**, you can disable this feature from **Stores** > **Configuration** > **Customers** > **Customer Configuration** > **Create New Account Options** > **Require Emails Confirmation**.

Once you disable this feature, you can create customer account directly from the front end.

If you do not have access to admin panel, then here is the code for simple module, which will allow you to create customer account from CLI command:

//file: app/code/XTeam/Customer/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'XTeam_Customer',
    __DIR__
);
```

//file: app/code/XTeam/Customer/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="XTeam_Customer"/>
</config>
```

//file: app/code/XTeam/Customer/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="customer_user_create" xsi:type="object">XTeam\Customer\Console\Command\CustomerCreateCommand</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>
    </config>
```

//file: app/code/XTeam/Customer/Console/Command/CustomerCreateCommand.php

```
<?php
namespace XTeam\Customer\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Magently\Customer\Helper\Customer;

class CustomerUserCreateCommand extends Command
{
    protected $customerHelper;

    public function __construct(Customer $customerHelper)
    {
        $this->customerHelper = $customerHelper;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('customer:user:create')
            ->setDescription('Create new customer')
            ->setDefinition($this->getOptionsList());
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('<info>Creating new user...</info>');
        $this->customerHelper->setData($input);
        $this->customerHelper->execute();

        $output->writeln('');
        $output->writeln('<info>User created with the following data:</info>');
        $output->writeln('<comment>Customer ID: ' . $this->customerHelper->getCustomerId());
        $output->writeln('<comment>Customer Website ID ' . $input->getOption(Customer::KEY_WEBSITE));
        $output->writeln('<comment>Customer First Name: ' . $input->getOption(Customer::KEY_FIRSTNAME));
        $output->writeln('<comment>Customer Last Name: ' . $input->getOption(Customer::KEY_LASTNAME));
        $output->writeln('');
        $output->writeln('<comment>Customer Email: ' . $input->getOption(Customer::KEY_EMAIL));
        $output->writeln('<comment>Customer Password: ' . $input->getOption(Customer::KEY_PASSWORD));
    }

    protected function getOptionsList()
    {
        return [
            new InputOption(Customer::KEY_FIRSTNAME, null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, '(Required) Customer first name'),
            new InputOption(Customer::KEY_LASTNAME, null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, '(Required) Customer last name'),
            new InputOption(Customer::KEY_EMAIL, null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, '(Required) Customer email'),
            new InputOption(Customer::KEY_PASSWORD, null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, '(Required) Customer password'),
            new InputOption(Customer::KEY_WEBSITE, null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, '(Required) Website ID'),
            new InputOption(Customer::KEY_SENDEMAIL, 0, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, '(1/0) Send email? (default 0)')
        ];
    }
}
```

//file: app/code/XTeam/Customer/Helper/Customer.php

```
<?php
namespace XTeam\Customer\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\App\State;
use \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input;

class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const KEY_EMAIL = 'customer-email';
    const KEY_FIRSTNAME = 'customer-firstname';
    const KEY_LASTNAME = 'customer-lastname';
    const KEY_PASSWORD = 'customer-password';
    const KEY_WEBSITE = 'website';
    const KEY_SENDEMAIL = 'send-email';

    protected $storeManager;
    protected $state;
    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $data;
    protected $customerId;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        State $state,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function setData(Input $input)
    {
        $this->data = $input;
        return $this;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->state->setAreaCode('frontend');

        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer
            ->setWebsiteId($this->data->getOption(self::KEY_WEBSITE))
            ->setEmail($this->data->getOption(self::KEY_EMAIL))
            ->setFirstname($this->data->getOption(self::KEY_FIRSTNAME))
            ->setLastname($this->data->getOption(self::KEY_LASTNAME))
            ->setPassword($this->data->getOption(self::KEY_PASSWORD))
            ->setConfirmation(1);
        $customer->save();

        $this->customerId = $customer->getId();

        if($this->data->getOption(self::KEY_SENDEMAIL)) {
            $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
        }        
    }

    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return (int)$this->customerId;
    }
}
```

Now let’s install the module:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Now, let’s add a new user according to the usage pattern.

```
php bin/magento customer:user:create --customer-firstname="John" --customer-lastname="Doe" --customer-email="john@example.com" --customer-password="john123#" --website="1"
```

Let me know if it helped.